# Querying sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a database for my game, everything is working until I want to query one item.

I have been trying few different methods and I can't make it work. I just simply don't see the error in my code.

The code is as follows:

```
   public Item getItem(String icon) {
       String[] columns = {KEY_ID, KEY_TYPE, KEY_ICON, KEY_LEVEL, KEY_ARMOR, KEY_DAMAGE, KEY_BUY, KEY_SELL};
       Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, KEY_ICON + "=" + icon,
       null, null, null, null);
      Item item=null;
       if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           item= new Item(cursor.getString(TYPE_COLUMN), 
                     cursor.getString(ICON_COLUMN),
                     cursor.getString(LEVEL_COLUMN),
                     cursor.getString(ARMOR_COLUMN),
                     cursor.getString(DAMAGE_COLUMN),
                     cursor.getString(BUY_COLUMN),
                     cursor.getString(SELL_COLUMN)
                           );
       }
       return item;
   }
```

The error I'm getting is

> No such column: fast_boots (code 1): while compiling: SELECT id, type,
>   icon, level, armor, damage, buy, sell from items where icon=fast_boots

When trying to find .getItem("fast_boots"); I do see the fast_boots in my sql database

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is the cursor null, or empty? Are you getting the wrong values in your new Item() constructor? Please add more details if you want to receive answers

Answer (score 1):

To make the query work, maybe you should try this :

```
KEY_ICON + "= '" + icon + "' "
```

As '`icon`' is a string value. Since you're not specifying it, it is probably trying to understand it as being a column in the projection

This is the wrong way of implementing such functionality, though. Do not perform database queries on the `getItem()` method itself (main thread), it deserves to run in background, so it won't affect the main thread.

Please read about [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, KEY_ICON + "='" + icon +"'",
       null, null, null, null);
```

I added `'`